# QUERY " IF NOT EXISTS " .... why it doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I have a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE_DELETE_ON_SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
BEFORE DELETE ON SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE temp_prima_tappa INTEGER;
DECLARE temp_ultima_tappa INTEGER;

-- NOW THIS QUERY WILL FAIL;   it checks if the record that has to be deleted is in the table
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht
                WHERE OLD.IDsentiero=sht.IDsentiero and OLD.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa) THEN

                        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE: La tappa indicata non è nel sentiero; impossibile elimnarla';

END IF;
```

**IDsentiero and IDtappa are PK** of of their relative tables: **IDsentiero for SENTIERO, IDtappa for TAPPA.**

The problem is that the **DELETE QUERY doesn't reply me with that error message**; simply **it let runs DELETE QUERY, although it cannot delete anything**, because that record doesn't exist in the table.

The problem is that query.. i'm sure but i cannot find the bug.

Comment: Where's your second table, OLD?

Comment: Exucse me. it's a delete trigger (row trigger)... i think OLD.column it's about the column of the record deleted... do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
declare recsexist int;
set recsexist = 0;  

SELECT 1 INTO recsexist 
FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht
WHERE OLD.IDsentiero=sht.IDsentiero and OLD.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa;

IF (recsexist > 0) THEN
     ...

END IF;
```

Comment: But why is it incorrect my version?? IF NOT EXISTS  should be correct, because if no one record satisfy that condition (so that record doesn't exist)  that signal should be raised... what do you think?

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana -- just doesn't work that way in MySQL -- your above code would run fine in MSSQL for example.  Best of luck.

Comment: hehe i know it doesn't work on mysql ^^ So you think that's just a matter of dbms, ok, at least it's not my fault

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using a DELETE trigger and looking at OLD -- the record has to exist in OLD for the DELETE trigger to be fired.  Hence the reason you're always seeing that text.  Sorry, didn't see that before.

Comment: if i wanted to check OLD.column=NEW.column would i have to use AFTER DELETE?

Comment: NEW doesn't exist in a DELETE trigger -- nothing new coming in.  What exactly are you trying to delete?

Comment: yes excuse me... wrong example... anyway in BEFORE DELETE i can't use OLD statement, right?
First: i have to check that the record the user woul delete must exist in te table, if not ----> error msg

Comment: So in BEFORE DELETE..... i don't know the record will might be deleted.. and i can't check if the DELETE should continue... and with an AFTER UPDATE the DELETE has already happened, so i can only do a rollback... right?

Answer (score 0):

Delete triggers are only run on rows that are actually deleted, so by the time the trigger runs, the row must exist. You can't use triggers to find delete statements that have no effect.

Comment: excuse me, the difference between the BEFORE and AFTER triggers, what is? Are you telling me in the BEFORE it doesn't exist the OLD record?

Comment: No, it always exists before the trigger, and never exists after the trigger, because this is the condition for triggering the trigger.

Comment: Ok but in the DELETE trigger there isn't the NEW... so in the BEFORE DELETE, because of a DELETE trigger, there would exist OLD statement that refers to a column (i'm speaking about row triggers)

Comment: I didn't see your comment before because I hadn't reloaded the site properly and my browser wasn't picking up the changes properly, but I don't know what you're trying to ask there. When a delete trigger runs, you are guaranteed that the old values refer to an existing row, since that's the point of the trigger.

Comment: Yes.. so in the BEFORE DELETE, as you've told me, the OLD statement still exists. So, i want to ask; if in that table **SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA** there isn't the record i want to delete, the trigger would signal me that event.. but it doesn't happen; and trust me, that record exist in the table. Tomorrow i will upload for you something, if you agree -please- (sql file or upload in sqlfiddle)

Comment: You can view how this doesn't work on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b1cc/1/0 **Remember to paste the body of the trigger in it** ( i tried to fix a syntax error, but it in mysql works, on sqlfiddle i can't find the bug).

Comment: No, because if no record exists, then there is nothing to trigger, your trigger does not even execute.